Oscilloscope or Logic Analyzer for Studying Serial Communication?
I have been programming microcontrollers with serial interfaces (the usual: I2C, SPI and UART) mostly for learning purposes and would like to see the signals, if they conform to the timing diagrams in my books, datasheets and online tutorials, hopefully to get a better understanding. I was wondering if a logic analyzer or an oscilloscope would be more appropriate for this. As a student, I couldn't afford either, but I was recently employed and with a little disposable income, I thought it would a nice beginner educational investment. Are the relatively inexpensive ones worth considering? Any insight is appreciated!

It depends what aspect of the serial comms you are interested in. The signal might look fine on a logic analyzer and yet the oscilloscope will show the problem. The signal might look fine on oscilloscope, but logic analyzer can show a problem easily. It depends what the problem is. What kind of things you expect to be interested in? You can get a suitable logic analyzer for like $10-$20 so why even bother thinking about getting one. Yes, it will be a cheap clone of a clone so you are on your own without support but yet they are useful and work with open-source software.

@Justme thanks. cheap options are welcome. As for what kind of serial comm I am interested in, I'm not thinking of anything too fancy or high speed. Say I2C at standard 100 kps mode, UART at 9600 bps (maybe 115200 bps but not a priority) and SPI at 1-4 MHz.

Asking for what to buy is off-topic so no suggestions. Yes those are doable but it does not help determining if you need a logic analyzer or an oscilloscope for them, because like I said, it depends on at what level you want to analyze the signals.

Many modern oscilloscopes have capabilities to decode serial busses. They can also measure analog signals (so you can see if the signal levels are ok and signal shape is not too messed up). But they are pretty big and expensive. Many oscilloscopes can be extended to use a logic analyzer with many channels to also look at fast parallel busses.
But that is probably all too expensive and overkill. For what you describe a cheap USB logic analyzer like the Sparkfun  TOL-18627 an easily be enough. There are other, more capable devices on the market.
But I think with a device that cheap you can't go wrong.

The oscilloscope may be an option, but the bus decoders may be a add-on you need to purchase, and for SPI you need a more expensive 4-channel oscilloscope anyway. And you cannot use the oscillocope as a data logger for recording bus for minutes before a problem appears on bus. Scope and logic analyzer are two different tools for debugging completely different aspects of a bus in different domains.

I recommeng getting a USB logic analyzer that fits your budget and using the oscilloscope for analog applicatoins.  The issue with the oscilloscope approach is that it is quote a pain to look at long data streams, at least on all the oscilloscopes I've tried, while the logic analyzer will usually have a PC interface that makes it much easier to look at a data capture.
